# value_counts() error in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I want to view the value counts of 79 columns.But I get an error.What is the error in this code??

```
for x in range(len(train.columns)):
        train.columns[x].value_counts()
```

I get

```
 train.columns[x].value_counts()

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value_counts'
```

Comment: the type stored inside `columns[x]` is a string. it has no attribute value_counts().  Did you read the error message? Read: [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and debug your values...

Comment: When is execute train['Street'].value_counts() it gives the output.But when I do it in for loop iam getting this error

Comment: Also: Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Questions should contain copy&paste code so we can verify your error and advise on howto fix it. Your code is not copy&pasteable, nor can we verify your error.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating through column labels instead of columns. I think you want to do the following instead:

```
for col in train.columns:
    train[col].value_counts()
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem but this may be another solution to another problem